# Drupal 7 Mysql query (Insert)

Tags: mysql, drupal-7

I'm new to Drupal.
So I was wondering if you can help me.

I saw a lot of documents regarding the Drupal API mysql thing-y and It's been bugging me that I have to study once more to finish my work done.

And here's the documentation that I'm applying to my problem

[image]

Regarding my problem about the **INSERT** function, I have this table entitled **embed**

[image]

and here is my data from the table embed.

[image]

Then on my **basic page** I'm trying to insert a query.

```
$id = db_insert("embed")
    ->fields(array(
        'uid' => 1,
        'fbp_id' => 22222,
        'prom_stat' => 3333,
        'status' => 1,
    ))
    ->execute();
```

Instead of inserting a data to the table, it outputs an error like this.
[image]

Anyone knows the solution for this stuff? I'm really confused about this right now.

Comment: I'm starting to learn drupal myself, but I think your issue is MYSQL related.  In your table, all the fields that say NULL = NO, need to have values inserted into them in your insert sql statement, OR, a default value listed in mysql table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @steve has suggested in the comment, the issue is not on drupal side but on MySql side. You need to modify your insert code to

```
$id = db_insert("embed")
    ->fields(array(
        'uid' => 1,
        'fbp_id' => 22222,
        'prom_stat' => 3333,
        'status' => 1,
        'prom_id' => 0,
        'sweep_stat' => 0,
        'sweep_id' => 0,
        'comp_id' => 0,
        'comp_stat' => 0,
        'polls_stat' => 0,
        'polls_id' => 0
    ))
    ->execute();
```

Since i can see that your MySql table already contains value, i assume the earlier inserts where done by explicitly providing all values, instead of relying on default values for the field in MySql configuration.

Whenever you have a PDOException you should read it carefully for clues. These kind of errors are really very verbal and gives lots of pointers to resolve the issues. For example in your case,

> 'prom_id' doesn't have a default value

explains a lot.